# How to deserialize xml response to objects

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I am getting the xml response something like this and when i am trying to deserialize it to objects i couldn't able to do this. values are getting null.

my response is here

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">15</int>
</response

response res = new response(); 
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.LoadXml(XmlString); 
XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc.DocumentElement);
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(res.GetType()); 
object obj = ser.Deserialize(reader); // Then you just need to cast obj into whatever type it is, e.g.: response myObj = (response)obj; 

public class response 
{ 
public string responseHeader { get; set; } 
public int status { get; set; } 
public int QTime { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: my response is here <response><lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">15</int></response>

Comment: response res = new response(); XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(XmlString);
            XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc.DocumentElement);
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(res.GetType());
            object obj = ser.Deserialize(reader);
            // Then you just need to cast obj into whatever type it is, e.g.:
            response myObj = (response)obj;

 public class response
    {
        public string responseHeader { get; set; }
        public int status { get; set; }
        public int QTime { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Your XML doesn't look like it is in the format that XmlSerializer knows how to handle.
See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73.aspx).

You will either have to generate the XML correctly or if you are required to understand this (strange) XML form, you will have to write your own deserialization code.  Or, perhaps, transform it with XSLT first.